Remote Desktop Error code: 0x3 Extended error code: 0x18
What causes remote desktop client to get Error code: 0x3 Extended error code: 0x18?
I get this error code from my client on Windows 10 to a host on Windows 10. I previously had no problem connecting to. I can connect to the same host from remote desktop clients on other machines without error. I've searched extensively and can find other reports of the same error code but nothing mentioning this extended error code. I've found some recommendations that suggest modifying the registry, but that has not helped. I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the client. What does this error code and extended error code mean?

Please note that the Title of the question is usually not the place people expect to find the error code or the entire question. The Title tells people a little bit ABOUT your question, and then the body needs to have a clear description of the problem, any logs or messages or error codes, what you've tried so far, and a clear question.

I've also answered my question. This is a simple issue without any solution elsewhere on the internet. I'm hoping to help others with the same error by succinctly posting it without unnecessary verbosity so that indexing and searching can help others.

Excellent. Solving your own question is a good thing. Please recognize, though, that while is it a good thing to try to be succinct, you are presenting your question to others online for help, and we only know what you've told us, and so competing with conciseness is the necessity of "cogency", that is, you need to present ENOUGH information, AND not TOO MUCH information. Way back in college, a business communication professor had this helpful phrase "concise, yet cogent".

Thanks. What else is needed here?

You've made the edit. Just wait. If the community members agree, the post will be reopened.

This extended error code seems to indicate that the host can not push the resolution requested by the client. You should be able to overcome this issue by reducing the display size requestd by your client. One way to do this is by leaving full screen mode and reducing the size of the window. Depending on your client, before connecting there may be additional options to specify the output size.
In retrospect, I believe my issue started after I removed a discrete GPU from my headless host to reduce energy usage. Adding a discrete GPU can overcome this issue while still running full screen.
